# Unable to perform UNION operation only on certain relations in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig, union

I am having an issue with UNION in Pig which I have not been able to resolve. When I do UNION on some relations in the same script it works fine but on other relations it does not work. I am performing the UNION on two relations namely `one` and `two`. And it won't work on these two relations and so many of the other relations. Here is my script:

```
A = LOAD '/home/biadmin/datasets/Datasets/HomeA/2014/homeA2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Date:chararray ,use:float, gen:float, FurnaceHRV:float, CellarOutlets:float, WashingMachine:float, FridgeRange:float, DisposalDishwasher:float, KitchenLights:float, BedroomOutlets:float, BedroomLights:float, MasterOutlets:float, MasterLights:float, DuctHeaterHRV:float);
C = FOREACH A GENERATE Date,SUM(TOBAG(use..)) AS total:float, '1388552400' AS unixconst1:chararray, '86400' AS dayconst1:chararray;                                        
hourly = FILTER C BY ENDSWITH(Date, '00'); 
hourlymd = FOREACH hourly GENERATE *, SUBSTRING(Date,0,INDEXOF(Date,'/',0)) as month1:chararray, SUBSTRING(Date,INDEXOF(Date,'/',0)+1,LAST_INDEX_OF(Date,'/')) as day1:chararray, SUBSTRING(Date,LAST_INDEX_OF(Date,'/')+1,INDEXOF(Date,' ',0)) as year1:chararray, SUBSTRING(Date,INDEXOF(Date,' ',0)+1,INDEXOF(Date,':',0)) as hour1:chararray;                                                             
hourlymdB = FOREACH hourlymd GENERATE (int)(hour1) AS hour:int, (int)(day1) AS day:int, (int)(month1) AS month:int,  (int)(year1) AS year:int, (int)(unixconst1) AS unixconst:int, (int)(dayconst1) AS dayconst:int;
SPLIT hourlymdB INTO 
        one IF(month==1),
        two IF(month==2),
        three IF(month==3),
        four IF(month==4),
        five IF(month==5),
        six IF(month==6),
        seven IF(month==7),
        eight IF(month==8),
        nine IF(month==9),
        ten IF(month==10),
        eleven IF(month==11),
        twelve IF(month==12),
        rest OTHERWISE;

yearone = UNION one, two;

STORE yearone INTO '/home/biadmin/datasets/output/yearone';
```

This code does not work and there is not error. Here is the output when I run it.

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 0: java.lang.NullPointerException

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:283)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1367)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1352)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1341)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:392)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:375)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:232)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:608)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$4.run(Job.java:963)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$4.run(Job.java:961)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:366)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskReports(Job.java:961)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getTaskReports(HadoopShims.java:218)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.addMapReduceStatistics(MRJobStats.java:353)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:233)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:165)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:364)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:277)
    ... 16 more
================================================================================
```

However, If perform the UNION on `A` and `C`, and write:

```
yearone = UNION A, C;
```

Then it works fine with no problem and stores the relation in the destination. I cannot figure out why? I have run it both in `grunt>` (local mode) shell and outside using `pix -x local 'file.pig'` command.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the syntax of `UNION A, C` and `yearone = onev UNION twov`. The second UNION syntax is incorrect.Change it to

```
yearone =  UNION onev, twov;
```

Note:I don't see onev and twov relations in your script.I am assuming you have those in your script.

Comment: You are right. This was incorrect syntax.I did change it to 'UNION one, two;'.  Again, the only relation that  I can do UNION on are 'A', 'C', and 'hourly'.

Comment: Check to see if you have records in the other relations.